# window.alert not running when button clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have the message "Parents have been alerted" to display in a window alert screen when a button is clicked, but so far I'm not able to get the message to display.

JS:

```
var thirtyMinDelayButton = document.querySelector("30-minute-delayed-button");
var hourDelayButton = document.querySelector("hour-delayed-button");
var cancelledButton = document.querySelector("cancelled-button");

/*
 * event listeners
 */
thirtyMinDelayButton.onclick = function() {
  window.alert("Parents have been alerted");
};
```

HTML:

```
 <article id="contentstart">
      <h2>Football</h2>
      <p>Click a button below to update the schedule.</p>
      <div class="changes">
        <p class="30-minute-delayed-button">30 Minute Delay</p>
        <p class="hour-delayed-button">hour Delay</p>
        <p class="cancelled-button">Cancelled</p>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Why is it that this message isn't displaying, because from what I understand so far of JS it should work.

Comment: because your selectors are all wrong.... You are looking for `<30-minute-delayed-button>` element, not a class. The errror message in your console should clearly state that.

Comment: The error message you get when you run the code seems quite clear.

Comment: `<p>` is the element used to create a paragraph. If you want a button, then use a `<button>`.

Comment: Selecting a class works just like in CSS, you need to put a `.` before the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
var thirtyMinDelayButton = document.querySelector(".30-minute-delayed-button");
```

I had a quick look on the Document.queryselector Mozilla developer site and it looks good, only thing I could see was a period before the class name?

[Mozilla Developer Site - QuerySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: I tried that and that doesn't work. I guess maybe the button itself could not be registering, but  I don't know why it wouldn't be.

Comment: <p id="30-minute-delayed-button" onClick="myFunction()">30 Minute Delay</p>     function myFunction() {
    window.alert("hi");
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform any kind of action on these elements:

```
var thirtyMinDelayButton = document.querySelector("30-minute-delayed-button");
var hourDelayButton = document.querySelector("hour-delayed-button");
var cancelledButton = document.querySelector("cancelled-button");
```

Then change them to this:

```
var thirtyMinDelayButton = document.querySelector(".30-minute-delayed-button");
var hourDelayButton = document.querySelector(".hour-delayed-button");
var cancelledButton = document.querySelector(".cancelled-button");
```

They are CSS selectors and thus need to have a period before the class name when using document.querySelector